# Check if the image and file type exist inside directory

Tags: php, image, file, file-type

This is my code:

```
$file = 'images/img_' . $post->_id . '.jpg'; // images/img_1.jpg
    if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
                //show the image
                echo '<img src="' . $file . '" class="img-responsive" />';
            } 
            else {
                // show default image 
                echo '<img src="images/default.gif" class="img-responsive" />'; 
            }
```

What this basicly does is to check if the an image (eg img_1.jpg) exist in my images folder and display it, if not it shows a default image.

This works fine, the only problem, as you probably 've seen, is that it checks only the .jpg files and not *.gif or *.png too (the file could also be img_1.gif or img_1.png, right? ) .

How can I make sure that it will check against all valid file types too and show the file with the correct format?

Comment: you could pull all of the images in the directory into an array and then check to see if the image name is in the array and echo if it is. It's sloppy but it's one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way to do this is probably to store the extension in the database, that way you're not scanning your file system for matches.

However, you could also use the [`glob();`](http://php.net/glob); function and check if results has anything.

`$result = glob('images/img_' . $post->_id . '.*');`

If you want to further narrow down your extension types you can do that like this:

`$result = glob('images/img_' . $post->_id . '.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE)`

New code might look something like this (untested but you get the idea):

```
$result = glob('images/img_' . $post->_id . '.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

if(!empty($result)) { 
    //show the image
    echo '<img src="' . $result[0]. '" class="img-responsive" />';
} else {
    // show default image 
    echo '<img src="images/default.gif" class="img-responsive" />'; 
}
```

Comment: So I can use this glob('images/img_' . $post->_id . '.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) inside a foreach loop and show the image with the correct format and avoid the if statement, or do I need adn the if too?

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through an array of file extensions and check them i've made a sample script to show what i mean listed below

```
$array = array('.jpg','.png','.gif');
foreach($array as $key => $value){

    $file = 'images/img_' . $post->_id . $value; // images/img_1.jpg
    if (file_exists($file) && is_file($file)) {
       $filefound = '<img src="' . $file . '" class="img-responsive" />';
    } 
} 

if(isset($filefound)){
    echo $filefound; 
}else{
    echo '<img src="images/default.gif" class="img-responsive" />'; 
}
```

Comment: This won't work, you are echoing inside of the foreach loop so you will ALWAYS get at least 2 default images displayed, and then either 1 found image or a 3rd default.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that your script will check only for `.jpg` not for others because you have written statically the file extension.

```
$file = 'images/img_' . $post->_id . '.jpg'; 
                                         ^
```

Now Make change in this line to make available the extension dynamically. I am supposing that you are storing  the image name with extension than:

```
   $file = 'images/img_' . $post->_id . $post->image_name;
```

Note : $post->image_name should be like :

```
$post->image_name = abc.png (image_name.extension);
```